# SVC python output showing the same value of "1" for every C or gamma used

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, svm

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
numere=np.fromfile("sat.trn",dtype=int,count=-1,sep=" ")
numereTest=np.fromfile("sat.tst",dtype=int,count=-1,sep=" ")
numere=numere.reshape(int(len(numere)/37),37)
numereTest=numereTest.reshape(int(len(numereTest)/37),37)
etichete=numere[0:int(len(numere)),36]
eticheteTest=numereTest[0:int(len(numereTest)),36]
numere=np.delete(numere,36,1)
numereTest=np.delete(numereTest,36,1)
clf=svm.SVC(kernel='rbf',C=1,gamma=1)
clf.fit(numere,etichete)
predictie=clf.predict(numereTest)
```

I took the data from a file that has it all and then I made 2 np.arrays with them, but the output is 1 everything I do.

numere(:10)-->array([[ 92, 115, 120,  94,  84, 102, 106,  79,  84, 102, 102,  83, 101,
126, 133, 103,  92, 112, 118,  85,  84, 103, 104,  81, 102, 126,
134, 104,  88, 121, 128, 100,  84, 107, 113,  87],
[ 84, 102, 106,  79,  84, 102, 102,  83,  80, 102, 102,  79,  92,
112, 118,  85,  84, 103, 104,  81,  84,  99, 104,  78,  88, 121,
128, 100,  84, 107, 113,  87,  84,  99, 104,  79],
[ 84, 102, 102,  83,  80, 102, 102,  79,  84,  94, 102,  79,  84,
103, 104,  81,  84,  99, 104,  78,  84,  99, 104,  81,  84, 107,
113,  87,  84,  99, 104,  79,  84,  99, 104,  79],
[ 80, 102, 102,  79,  84,  94, 102,  79,  80,  94,  98,  76,  84,
99, 104,  78,  84,  99, 104,  81,  76,  99, 104,  81,  84,  99,
104,  79,  84,  99, 104,  79,  84, 103, 104,  79],
[ 84,  94, 102,  79,  80,  94,  98,  76,  80, 102, 102,  79,  84,
99, 104,  81,  76,  99, 104,  81,  76,  99, 108,  85,  84,  99,
104,  79,  84, 103, 104,  79,  79, 107, 109,  87],
[ 80,  94,  98,  76,  80, 102, 102,  79,  76, 102, 102,  79,  76,
99, 104,  81,  76,  99, 108,  85,  76, 103, 118,  88,  84, 103,
104,  79,  79, 107, 109,  87,  79, 107, 109,  87],
[ 76, 102, 106,  83,  76, 102, 106,  87,  80,  98, 106,  79,  80,
107, 118,  88,  80, 112, 118,  88,  80, 107, 113,  85,  79, 107,
113,  87,  79, 103, 104,  83,  79, 103, 104,  79],
[ 76, 102, 106,  87,  80,  98, 106,  79,  76,  94, 102,  76,  80,
112, 118,  88,  80, 107, 113,  85,  80,  95, 100,  78,  79, 103,
104,  83,  79, 103, 104,  79,  79,  95, 100,  79],
[ 76,  89,  98,  76,  76,  94,  98,  76,  76,  98, 102,  72,  80,
95, 104,  74,  76,  91, 104,  74,  76,  95, 100,  78,  75,  91,
96,  75,  75,  91,  96,  71,  79,  87,  93,  71],
[ 76,  94,  98,  76,  76,  98, 102,  72,  76,  94,  90,  76,  76,
91, 104,  74,  76,  95, 100,  78,  76,  91, 100,  74,  75,  91,
96,  71,  79,  87,  93,  71,  79,  87,  93,  67]])

Comment: can you provide numere and numere test head? we need to see the data to be able to help, your code is kinda ugly but looks ok, and change `numere[0:int(len(numere)),36]` to  `numere[:,36]` (wont resolve problem but increases readability)

Comment: The train file with the values has 4000 lines, I will give you one of them now "92 115 120 94 84 102 106 79 84 102 102 83 101 126 133 103 92 112 118 85 84 103 104 81 102 126 134 104 88 121 128 100 84 107 113 87 3" where the last number on every line is what I should use for etichete. If this is not enough I will try to search for the website from were I got these values.

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Statlog+(Landsat+Satellite) (this is the website)

Comment: use `numere[:10]` and edit your question with output so I see at least 10 rows, could you describe the data as well? there is a possibility that some of your labels are holding direct answer to target - such as number of goals will surely tell the classifier which team wins (example)

Comment: So, the problem is something like this: you have 36 values on every line that mean values for a 3x3 pixel neighbourhood, every pixel has 4 values, so 4x9 pixels=36 values. The last value on the line means the terrain it sees:1,2,3,4,5,6,7 that mean different kind of "textures" and I have to implement a SVM that can predict what terrain the pixels would see.

Comment: I added the output as well in the question. Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: just one more question, the 1 you get means it always predicts label 1 or that accuracy is 1?

Comment: It predicts label 1, predictie in the output is just a bunch of 1s screenshoot here : https://imgur.com/sgNBipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the most likely reason for what you get is:

Firstly you do not use scaling for the data, try to use [standard scaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(numere)
numere = scaler.transform(numere)
numereTest = scaler.transform(numereTest)
```

Secondly you are not tuning your parameters, you need to select the best fitting parameters, I strongly recommend using [grid search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). You can find an example how to use it [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_grid_search_digits.html). Grid search is good for parameter tuning but take care to not use cross validation in this dataset, that is recommendation from its creators :) Gamma and C can get to wide values from very low decimal numbers to very high numbers, you can't test it properly manually.

Edit: you should not use CV so this is better way for you to do grid search

```
grid = { #edit ´this with more values
    'gamma': [0.001, 0.1, 10, 100, 1000, ],
    'C': [1, 10, 100]
}

for g in ParameterGrid(grid):
    clf.set_params(**g)
    clf.fit(numere, etichete)
    # save if best
    score = clf.score(numereTest, eticheteTest)
    if score > best_score:
        best_score = score
        best_grid = g

print ("best score:", best_score) 
print ("Grid:", best_grid)
```

Comment: I will try. I'm actually a beginner in this AI thing, and I don't know a lot of stuff and this is why I'm not sure I would be able to do it.

Comment: Your solution works, but for now I can't seem to understand how to use the standard scaler or the grid search, I just put a random gamma=0.0001 and it has now an accuracy of 90% percent with cost=4, do you have the time to show on my code how the grid search is implemented because I think I am idiot.

Comment: @Alexandru-CosminDan added samples, wrote them from head so sorry if there will be some syntax problem

Comment: I think maybe I didn't understand the documentation on their website because yours is much easy to understand. Thank you very much, but what is ParameterGrid?

Comment: Solved it! Thank you!